# ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password logon denied when connecting to 19C database

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect to a schema on 19C local database. Ibefore it works very well but today I found this error ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied .

The username and password are DEFINITELY correct - can anyone think of a reason why this wouldn't work?

plz any help
[image]

Comment: Maybe the password expired? If you can log in as a privileged account like SYS you can look at `dba_users` to see the current account state. Or maybe you've changed the connection from CDB to PDB or something - maybe in your tnsnames.ora if it's affecting multiple clients. The password having expired (or just being wrong - are you sure you're entering it in the right case?) seems more likely though.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for your quick interaction . I change the password and re try to connect but it s same.The account_status = open . I have local database so i didn't have pluggable database :)

Comment: If you're sure that the password is correct - including the case, and any special characters (you haven't switched to the wrong keyboard layout for example) then it still sounds like you might be connecting to the wrong database/instance. or you're using proxy authentication and have lost the connect-through grant, but that seems unlikely too. Or you're trying to connect as SYS and have wrong role selected (i.e. not SYSDBA), or vice versa. Can't think of any other reason off-hand...

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks its same oky now i do :
ALTER USER OPS$HR IDENTIFIED BY ... ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

Comment: If the account was locked then the `account_status` would have been LOCKED not OPEN, and you would have got "ORA-28000: the account is locked" rather than ORA-01017. So I guess you were still giving the wrong password and that locked it; then you unlocked it and started using the right password. Anyway... glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Is `OPS$HR` is actually the username? If so, please post the output of the following queries: 
`select username, account_status, authentication_type from dba_users where username = 'OPS$HR';` 
and `select * from v$parameter where name = 'os_authent_prefix';`

Comment: @pmdba the spool of the queries is below: query1:OPS$HR OPEN PASSWORD query2:3683 os_authent_prefix 2 OPS$ OPS$ OPS$ TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE prefix for auto-logon accounts  4201741605 0

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by executing the commands below :

ALTER USER OPS$HR IDENTIFIED BY ... ACCOUNT UNLOCK;